# haskell if else statement with multiple conditions

Tags: haskell

the goal is to Write a function that, given an integer between 1 and 12 evaluates to the name of the related month (1->January, etc.) Else, it may evaluate to "Incorrect month number".
This is my code:

```
list = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","April", "May", "Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
month x = if x<13 && x>0
          then x = list !! (x-1)
          else "Not a month"
```

this is the error msg: parse error on input "="

Many thanks for your help

Comment: @YassineBotabia: changing it to `||` would in fact change the semantics and generate errors. Furthemore the error is not with the `x = ` on the first line, but the one on the second line.

Comment: I realized shortly after puting. that's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `x =`. (Why did you write that?)

```
list = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","April","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
month x = if x<13 && x>0
          then list !! (x-1)
          else "Not a month"
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Using guards is the best strategy here:

```
month x | x > 0 && x < 13      = list !! (x - 1)
        |otherwise             = "Error"
```

You could also use `Maybe` for this type of operation:

```
mylist = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","April", "May", "Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

exampleFunc :: [String] -> Int -> Maybe String
exampleFunc li int
   | int > 0 && int < 13    = Just (li !! (int - 1))
   | otherwise              = Nothing
```

Using `Maybe` allows you to return a standard value (`Nothing`) in the event of an `otherwise` condition.

Comment: Thank you Barbra, you comments are very helpful .

Comment: `Maybe String` should absolutely be used here, since `"Not a month"` is not, in fact, a month.

Answer (score 2):

Well you write:

```
month x = if x0
          then x = list !! (x-1)
          else "Not a month"
```

You probably are used to the imperative world (C++, Java,...) where there are *variables* that you can set and set to other values. In a functional and by extent declarative language, a variable is only set once.

Furthermore there is no need to set `x` to a value, you only have to return `list!!(x-1)` so:

```
month x = if x<13 && x>0
          then list !! (x-1)
          else "Not a month"
```

should work.

An - in my opinion - more elegant way to write this however is using guards:

```
month x | x > 0 && x < 13 = list !! (x-1)
        | otherwise = "not a month"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. x= was my error. and you are right I just started functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it like this:

```
month = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","April", "May", "Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
getMonth k = lookup k $ zip [1..] month
```